# Convert functional component to class component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I got an app that is working on react using a class component, i found a code of a feature that i would like to add to my code but it's made using a functional component. The code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animate-in-view-gqcc8 but the relevant part is this.

```
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";
import "./styles.css";

function Box() {
  const controls = useAnimation();
  const [ref, inView] = useInView();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      controls.start("visible");
    }
  }, [controls, inView]);
```

I don't know how to add that controls variable in my class component

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      curtains: null,
      loading: true,
      renderNav: false
    };
  }
```

Should i add it on my state? i don't understand how to make it works in class component

Comment: Just render it like any other React component.  eg. inside `render` method, just `return <Box/>`..

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. The main logic seems to be in the hooks used by the `Box` component. Do you just want to render the `Box` component in your code or do you want to extract some features and use the code as a blueprint for your own code?

Comment: @trixn yes, i would like to add that feature into my component. i need to use that controls inside a component in my code. Need yo copy that useffect to my class component so i can use that "controls" variable inside my render

Comment: The problem is i need to declare that "controls" variable inside a hook, so idk if i need to declare it on my state

Comment: It would probably be easier to transform your component into a functional component so that you can use that hook. Otherwise you would need to write some kind of a wrapper. Every class component can be written as a functional component using hooks.

Comment: You don't need to *declare* the `controls` inside of any hook. The `useAnimation()` hook returns the `controls` object. Also you can't *declare a hook on a state*. That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use hooks inside of a class component. What you can do is to write a little wrapper that exposes the `ref` and `controls` in a render prop:

```
const Controls = ({children}) => {
    const controls = useAnimation();
    const [ref, inView] = useInView();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inView) {
            controls.start("visible");
        }
    }, [controls, inView]);

    return children(ref, controls);
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    // ...

    render() {
        return (
            <Controls>
                {(ref, controls) => (
                    <motion.div ref={ref} animate={controls}>
                        {/* content */}
                    </motion.div>
                )}
            </Controls>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this look the way to do this. I got an error on `return children(ref, controls)` children is not defined @trixn

Comment: It is part of React right? i need to use React.Children?

Comment: you are a genius! this works perfect, thank you so much bro

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have

```
const functionalComponent=()=>{
  return <h1>Functional componenet</h1>
}
```

and you want to change it to class component

use this import at the top:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
```

and change your code to something like this:

```
    Class functionalComponent extends Component{
       state={}
       render(){
           return <h1>functional component</h1>;
         }
    }
```

your functional component is now changed to class component.

And to use it in your existing class component , you don't need to change your functional component to class component unless you require local state.

with the introduction of react hooks that's also changed i.e, you don't have to change your functional component to class component if you plan to use hooks.

In your code : useEffect is a hook and you can't use it inside a class component.

I would recommend simply importing the functional component inside your class component and if you have to pass some value , you can pass it as a prop.

And as far as importing your functional component is concerned:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import Box from "./Box.js";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      curtains: null,
      loading: true,
      renderNav: false
    };
  render(){
  return(<Box/>);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use functional components anywhere like a class component. Btw is also using so no need to worry about the thing that you cannot use state in it.

Use:

```
<Box props={props}/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need to combine this Box component into my App component